# Simulating a Test Particle in a Kerr Spacetime $(M,\mathcal{O}, \mathcal{A},\nabla^{L.C.})$

Tags: resource-recommendations, simulations, geodesics, software, kerr-metric

The equations of motion for a test particle in a Kerr spacetime $(M,\mathcal{O}, \mathcal{A},\nabla^{L.C.})$ are dictated by four degrees of freedom (i.e. invariant mass $m$ in $p^\mu g_{\mu\nu}p^{\nu}=-m^2,$ the energy $E$, the Carter constant $Q, $ and the orbital angular momentum $L_z=-p_{\phi}$ in the spin direction). On the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric) for the Kerr metric, there is a simulation on the right-hand side of the trajectory equations section (see simulation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Orbit_around_a_rotating_Kerr_black_hole.gif)). By any chance, does anyone know of such a program (for Python) that I can use to simulate this, as shown in the aforementioned program implementation?

Comment: The animation was generated by the PSE user https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/24093/Симон-Тыран. Perhaps you could contact them by email and ask for a copy of the code? [Also, the equations of motion are in the wikipedia page you link; if anything you could just integrate them using RK4 or something like that]

Comment: Oh, the Mathematica code is in their webpage: http://notizblock.yukterez.net/viewtopic.php?p=225/

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps, I was not being scrupulous enough! @AccidentalFourierTransform

Comment: Are there any public code available that could produce the time-like trajectories in Kerr metric?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform To integrate the equations of motion mentioned in the Wikipedia page, one needs to give the value of the Carter constant since this is a constant of motion. If one is interested in the the case of marginally bound orbits ($E^2=1$), how to give the value of the Carter constant to integrate the equations?

Answer (score 1):

You can use some common technical computing tools like Octave (free) or Matlab or even Mathematica. Using a simple explicit numerical integrator like ode45 you can simulate any ODE, also like system you are asking of